# JavaFX - move TreeItem up down in TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a tree view that looks like this.

```
-Root
--Parent 1
----Child 1
----Child 2
----Child 3
--Parent 2
----Child 1
----Child 2
```

I've looked all over SO and Google but I can't find a proper way to move TreeItems up and down in the tree list. Is this possible?

I'm not talking about just moving the `child` nodes, rather when I move the parents up, I need the children to move with them as well. So moving `Parent 2` up would look like this.

```
-Root
--Parent 2
----Child 1
----Child 2
--Parent 1
----Child 1
----Child 2
----Child 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the TreeItem up in its parent childlist.

1. If you use a view-controller-model setup, do the reordering in the model, the tree shall update accordingly
2. If you only want the view to change and not the model use a reordering in the getChildren() method of the own TreeItem implementation
3. If your view also represents the model (data itself), then you might use the code below.

Run the following method on the node that shall move up:

```
static void moveUp(TreeItem item) {
    if (item.getParent() instanceof TreeItem) {
        TreeItem parent = item.getParent();
        List<TreeItem> list = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();
        Object prev = null;
        for (Object child : parent.getChildren()) {
            if (child == item) {
                list.add((TreeItem)child);
            } else {
                if (prev != null) list.add((TreeItem)prev);
                prev = child;
            }
        }
        if (prev != null) list.add((TreeItem)prev);
        parent.getChildren().clear();
        parent.getChildren().addAll(list);
    }
}
```

that is somehow ugly Java code, but works. Move down is similar.

The children will follow, as the TreeView redraws automatically

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. How would the move down work though? I tried modifying this but I get a duplicate `next` after the swap.

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary amount of code. Just do `int index = parent.getChildren().indexOf(item);` `parent.getChildren().remove(index);` `parent.getChildren().add(index+1, item);`. There is no need for the `if(...)` clause either, `getParent()` has a return type of `TreeItem`.

Comment: Nicer, but the parent could be NULL(root). and the index has to be checked if in bounds...

Comment: Of course, but you would presumably do those checks elsewhere (e.g. disable a button for moving up/down if it wasn't possible). Using `instanceof` to check for non-null is hardly intuitive (and I suspect it performs less well than `item.getParent() != null` too).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a [`SortedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) instead of an `ObservableList` as a backing list for your JavaFX `TreeView`.

On the `SortedList` there is a [`comparatorProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html#comparatorProperty--), whenever it changes, the `List` gets reordered accordingly. Easy as pie ;-)

Comment: That was what I ment with 2. ... its very elegant and generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void moveDown() {
    if (selectedItem != null) {
        TreeItem item = selectedItem;
        int index = item.getParent().getChildren().indexOf(item);
        if(index != item.getParent().getChildren().size()-1)
        {
            TreeItem safeItem = (TreeItem) item.getParent().getChildren().get(index+1);
            item.getParent().getChildren().set(index+1, item);
            item.getParent().getChildren().set(index, safeItem);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)